# PostgreSQL - Export a table to another with a different name but the same structure

Tags: bash, database, bash-scripting, sql, postgresql

I need to export one table (data only) to another table with different name but the same structure using PostgreSQL and psql tool. I would also like to export only certain records and just a few fields from the source table.

Could someone give me an example?

Thanks!

Comment: When you "down vote" a question, inform your reasons and what can be improved! This denotes cordiality and respect!

Comment: In my view, this question is clear. If you have questions see my answer below. Thank you!

Comment: Your question states no research effort and you don't give anything that you already tried. It also is stated as if you just want someone to write a script for you, not solve a problem you're have with the export.

Comment: @Confuzing Please see my answer below. I believe that my approach may be useful for people who do not understand much of bash script and PostgreSQL. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: The answer may be valid but the question could be added to or reworded to make it better. A phrase often used is  "superuser is not a script writing service", and that is how your question currently reads.

Comment: @Confuzing I tried to make another improvement on my question. Please judge if it's better. The original idea was get an example for someone who knows little about bash and SQL. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! Here's my hack! This is a "bash" approach!

**NOTE I:**
`<TARGET_DB_NAME>` -> Assume the same **table** name in the source and destination!
`<TARGET_TABLE_NAME>` -> Assume the same **database** name in the source and destination!

**NOTE II:** I use "fbcf111499a6467ba" as an unlikely name for the target table. The goal is to avoid problems in the execution of "sed".

**TO EXECUTE ON THE "SOURCE MACHINE"/"DATABASE"**

```
cd /tmp
sudo -u postgres psql <TARGET_DB_NAME> -c "CREATE TABLE fbcf111499a6467ba AS SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c FROM <TARGET_TABLE_NAME> WHERE <YOUR_SEARCH_QUERY>;"
sudo -u postgres pg_dump --file "/tmp/<TARGET_TABLE_NAME>.sql" --table=fbcf111499a6467ba --data-only --column-inserts "<TARGET_DB_NAME>"
sed -i 's/INSERT INTO fbcf111499a6467ba (/INSERT INTO <TARGET_TABLE_NAME> (/g' /tmp/<TARGET_TABLE_NAME>.sql
sudo -u postgres psql <TARGET_DB_NAME> -c "DROP TABLE fbcf111499a6467ba;"
```

**TO EXECUTE ON THE "TARGET MACHINE"/"DATABASE"**

```
cd /tmp
sudo -u postgres psql <TARGET_DB_NAME> < /tmp/<TARGET_TABLE_NAME>.sql
```